# How to Build cURL and use it in a Code::Blocks project (static)

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I know there are many topics about this but none of them helped me to solve my problem. All I want is to make a simple **C++** program that uses **cURL** with **static libcurl** (without DLL files) on **Code::Blocks - Windows 8**. I've spent around 20 hours trying to do this but all I found is unuseful stuff and stuff I don't understand.

After downloading **curl-7.39.0.zip** from **http://curl.haxx.se/download.html** and extracting it to my **Code::Block** directory, I ran **Developer Command Prompt for VS2013** as Administrator and entered the following:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\winbuild
nmake /f Makefile.vc mode=static vc=12 debug=no
```

The output of the second command was: **http://pastebin.com/bwPqxp9V**

Then I made a new empty **Code::Blocks** project with **Main.cpp**:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
int main() { curl_global_cleanup(); }
```

In **Code::Blocks**, I navigated to **Project > Build Options**
In **Compiler Settings > Defines**, I added `CURL_STATICLIB`
In **Linker Settings > Link Libraries**, I added the path of the .lib file generated (which exists):

```
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib
```

In **Linker Settings > Other Link Options**, I added `-static`
In **Search Directories > Compiler**, I added:

```
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\include
```

I may have edited some other stuff, but nothing important.
When I build using **GNU GCC Compiler** with the following command:

```
mingw32-g++.exe  -o Debug\MyTestProgram.exe Debug\Main.o  -static  "..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib"
```

I get **80 warnings** similar to:

```
.drectve `/DEFAULTLIB:"MSVCRT" /DEFAULTLIB:"OLDNAMES" ' unrecognized
```

And more than **50 errors**. What I did wrong and how can I fix it?
Feel free to ask me for more details if needed.

**Error log**:

```
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\easy.obj):(.text$mn+0x7)||undefined reference to `__security_cookie'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\easy.obj):(.text$mn+0x44)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\easy.obj):(.text$mn+0x64)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\multi.obj):(.text$mn+0x4)||undefined reference to `__security_cookie'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\multi.obj):(.text$mn+0x13b)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\multi.obj):(.text$mn+0x151)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\multi.obj):(.text$mn+0x4)||undefined reference to `__security_cookie'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\multi.obj):(.text$mn+0x10d)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\multi.obj):(.text$mn+0x295)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\multi.obj):(.text$mn+0x2ac)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\multi.obj):(.text$mn+0x4)||undefined reference to `__security_cookie'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\multi.obj):(.text$mn+0x17b)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\multi.obj):(.text$mn+0x2ea)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\cookie.obj):(.text$mn+0x7)||undefined reference to `__security_cookie'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\cookie.obj):(.text$mn+0x80)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\cookie.obj):(.text$mn+0x41d)||undefined reference to `_imp__strtoll'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\cookie.obj):(.text$mn+0x58f)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\cookie.obj):(.text$mn+0x754)||undefined reference to `_imp__strtoll'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\cookie.obj):(.text$mn+0x4)||undefined reference to `__security_cookie'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\cookie.obj):(.text$mn+0x45)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\cookie.obj):(.text$mn+0x57)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\curl_sspi.obj):(.text$mn+0x7)||undefined reference to `__security_cookie'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\curl_sspi.obj):(.text$mn+0xca)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\curl_sspi.obj):(.text$mn+0xfc)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\asyn-thread.obj):(.text$mn+0x4)||undefined reference to `__security_cookie'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\asyn-thread.obj):(.text$mn+0x5a)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\asyn-thread.obj):(.text$mn+0x91)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\asyn-thread.obj):(.text$mn+0x12e)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\asyn-thread.obj):(.text$mn+0x198)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\asyn-thread.obj):(.text$mn+0x1ae)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\asyn-thread.obj):(.text$mn+0x4)||undefined reference to `__security_cookie'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\asyn-thread.obj):(.text$mn+0xaa)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\hostip.obj):(.text$mn+0x4)||undefined reference to `__security_cookie'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\hostip.obj):(.text$mn+0x88)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\hostip.obj):(.text$mn+0x7)||undefined reference to `__security_cookie'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\hostip.obj):(.text$mn+0x178)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\hostip.obj):(.text$mn+0x4)||undefined reference to `__security_cookie'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\hostip.obj):(.text$mn+0x42)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\hostip.obj):(.text$mn+0x4)||undefined reference to `__security_cookie'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\hostip.obj):(.text$mn+0x7b)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\hostip.obj):(.text$mn+0x8e)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\url.obj):(.text$mn+0x7)||undefined reference to `__security_cookie'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\url.obj):(.text$mn+0x12c)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\url.obj):(.text$mn+0x7)||undefined reference to `__security_cookie'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\url.obj):(.text$mn+0xd5)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\url.obj):(.text$mn+0x115)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\url.obj):(.text$mn+0x4)||undefined reference to `__security_cookie'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\url.obj):(.text$mn+0xa4)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\url.obj):(.text$mn+0x1c6)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\curl-7.39.0\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl\lib\libcurl_a.lib(..\builds\libcurl-vc12-x86-release-static-ipv6-sspi-winssl-obj-lib\url.obj):(.text$mn+0x216)||undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'|
||More errors follow but not being shown.|
```

Comment: You cannot use the Visual Studio builds with Mingw/gcc/g++. If you want to do that then it HAS to be a dll. Otherwise build the library using gcc/g++/msys only.

Comment: @Brandon OK, can you please post an answer on how to do it with GCC?

Comment: Uh give me a sec. I'll post something.

Comment: Finished. Check the tutorial below. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Intro:

To build libcurl with gcc on windows, you need a command line tool. You may use Git-Bash or MSYS. Your choice.

- I'll be using MSYS: [MSYS1.0.11](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS/Base/msys-core/msys-1.0.11/MSYS-1.0.11.exe/download?use_mirror=softlayer-dal).
- I'll be using Mingw: [Mingw 4.8.1-rev5.7-sjlj-posix-threads](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.8.1/64-bit/threads-posix/sjlj/x64-4.8.1-release-posix-sjlj-rev5.7z/download)
- I'll be building Curl: [Curl-7.39.0](http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.39.0.tar.gz).

---

### Getting Started:

Start the MSYS installation. Choose whatever folder you like for the installation. When the command-line window pops up, answer as follows:

[image]

---

### PRE-SETUP:

Now you have a command-line tool "make" installed and is compatible with your gcc/g++/mingw.

BEFORE we run the commands, there's a few things you need to know:

- If using 32-bit gcc/g++ then change to: `--build=i686-pc-mingw32`.
- If using 64-bit gcc/g++ then change to: `--build=x86_64-w64-mingw32`.
- If using SSL, change `--without-ssl` to `--with-ssl` and add `-DOPENSSL_PATH=Path_To_Open_SSL_Here`.
- If you need to specify a special path to your ZLIB then add `-DZLIB_PATH=Path_To_ZLib_Here`.
- If you want to build STATIC then use `--disable-shared` otherwise don't use it OR use `--enable-shared`.

---

### Configuration:

Open MSYS.bat and run the following commands (modify as needed and described above):

```
$ cd "C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/curl-7.39.0"

$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --without-ssl --disable-shared --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib"
```

It should start doing a bunch of "checks". It will take a while so go get a coffee or something. If all is well and the configuration is complete, and you have everything setup correctly, then you should see the following:

[image]

---

### Building & Installing:

Finally, run the following commands:

```
$ make install-strip
```

It should now start building and it will install to (Wherever your MSYS installation is -- Mine is `C:/Msys`):

```
 C:/Msys/1.0/local/bin
 C:/Msys/1.0/local/include
 C:/Msys/1.0/local/lib
```

Those locations should have all the files necessary for you to use libcurl with gcc/g++/mingw.

If all went well, it will look like:
[image]

---

### OPTIONAL:

- You may either link to them in that location or move them.
- You can copy the files in "include", "lib" and "bin", into your mingw installation folder respectively (include + curl-folder to include, bin to bin, lib + package-folder to lib).