# Mingw32 Curl undefined reference to _imp__curl_global_init - trouble using -lcurl

Tags: c++, curl, linker, mingw

I was doing a project in which i needed to make HTTP request to access webpages,make downloads etc.. So i decided to use Curl.

I downloaded [curl-7.39.0-devel-mingw64.7z](http://curl.haxx.se/gknw.net/7.39.0/dist-w64/curl-7.39.0-devel-mingw64.7z) and extracted it and added the libraries, bin, and includes to mingw.

I am using Netbeans IDE. So i added **-lcurl** in project properties->linkers->additional options

but now i get the following errors.

> g++     -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/app build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/mainConnector.o  -lcurl
>   build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/mainConnector.o: In function `Z9connectorv':
>
> C:\Users\0xuser\Documents\NetBeansProjects\app/mainConnector.cpp:8: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_global_init'
>
> .
>
> .(some more similar errors)
>
> .
>
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I linked the library correctly right. Then why is this showing up?

> > > **Note**: I Googled about this and found about linking curl library by adding -lcurl but its not working for me. On my research i understood linking is a common problem for a newbie and even on *stackoverflow.com* we have similar questions(Oh yeah i readed these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604889/mingw32-curl-on-windows-7-error-undefined-reference-to-imp-curl-global-init ). But they only answer upto adding the -lcurl. They don't say about the possibilities for that to fail as in my case.

Comment: Instead, build it yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27609214/1462718

Comment: @bardon I did what u said using MYSYS with mingw but still got the same error.

Comment: add `-DCURL_STATICLIB` then try building your project.

Comment: @Brandon I was able to do the compiling when i set the configuration as static instead of application and adding -DCURL_STATICLIB. But that wont produce the executable. In order to do just that i need to compile it in application mode and in application mode it just didn't works. Give me the same error...