# How can I build curlpp on Windows for gcc?

Tags: c++, windows, curl, curlpp

I've downloaded the package from here: https://github.com/jpbarrette/curlpp
When I drag CMakelists.txt onto cmake.exe it does build something that looks like a Microsoft Visual Studio project. I want to build static library that I could use in Codeblocks with GCC instead. I've not idea how to do it, I don't know where the options are or how to set appropriate flags.
I've also followed this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27609214/7310666c which is about cURL - it build correctly, but when I linked it to my project it gave me undefined reference error.
Could anyone give me a hand here? My desktop is already littered by all the files I downloaded while trying.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generators.7.html):

> CMake [..] is responsible for writing the input files for a native
>   build system.

The modules responsible of creating files for a specific build system are called "Generators". For a full list of those generators, please have a look at [this](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generators.7.html).

In your case, by default it selects Visual Studio, even though "Code Blocks" should be available.

So, here's an example of how you could obtain the required files:

```
cd /path/to/curlpp/
mkdir build
cd build    
cmake -G "CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles" ..
```